# Suppress output from Codeship service

Tags: mongodb, logging, docker, codeship

I'm testing a container in Codeship that requires a database. Using services in codeship-services.yml I'm linking the database container to the application container. The problem is the database container is printing a lot of output that gets mixed with the output of the tests. I want to get rid of the MongoDB logs completely but MongoDB doesn't have options to do that.

I'm currently running it with
`mongod --quiet --setParameter logLevel=0` but getting a lot of output still.

So I'm looking for a solution on the Codeship side to suppress output from a container (service in Codeship terms). The

```
logging:
    driver: none
```

setting from docker-compose doesn't seem to work.

Here is my codeship-services.yml:

```
myapp:
  build:
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: myapp
  cached: true
  links:
    - database

database:
  image: mongo:3.4.3
  command: mongod --quiet --logpath /tmp/mongo.log --setParameter logLevel=0
```

Comment: `Logging` is currently a directive Codeship doesn't support yet.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to reroute the MongoDB logs to `/dev/null`, thereby getting rid of them entirely, you should replace the path for the log output specified by the key `--logpath`. For instance:

```
database:
  image: mongo:3.4.3
  command: mongod --quiet --logpath /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid completely of MongoDB logs, you can redirect all output of `mongod` command to `\dev\null`.

`mongod --quiet --logpath /tmp/mongo.log --setParameter logLevel=0 > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Unfortunately this fails when I run it using `jet steps`. If I add `> /dev/null` I get he following error:

    about to fork child process, waiting until server is ready for connections.
    {ContainerRunStdout=step_name:"Test" service_name:"database"}: forked process: 16
    {ContainerRunStdout=step_name:"Test" service_name:"database"}: ERROR: child process failed, exited with error number 1