# How to reduce mongo log verbosity in a docker-compose image?

Tags: mongodb, logging, docker-compose

I'm running MongoDB inside a larger server, controlled by docker-compose.

I'd like to reduce the verbosity of the Mongo logs (and probably eventually control other Mongo settings too).  Not sure where to fit this into my minimal config; I currently just have:

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    volumes:
      - ${MONGO_DATA_DB}:/data/db
    ports:
      - ${EXPOSED_MONGO_PORT}:27017
```

Comment: much better solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56303485/1121366

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Reading the description of the [official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo?tab=description) of MongoDB at DockerHub (same image you are using) I deduced that you can pass commands to *mongod* using **command** section of the docker-compose. Then you could use the `--quiet` option to limit the amount of output.

In this way you docker-compose would be as follows:

```
mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    volumes:
      - ${MONGO_DATA_DB}:/data/db
    ports:
      - ${EXPOSED_MONGO_PORT}:27017
    command: --quiet
```

You can find the entire list of options that *mongod* accepts [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/#core-options) or also check the `--help` output of `mongod` in your bash.

Sometimes docker images, accepts configuration params as an environment variables, so you could change the configuration of the service at runtime. Sadly I couldn't find any official information about available environment variables in this docker image, but I encourage you to continue investigating about this alternative path.

I hope it helps!

**EDIT**

Another approach from the image documentation:

> For a more complicated configuration setup, you can still use the MongoDB configuration file. mongod does not read a configuration file by default, so the --config option with the path to the configuration file needs to be specified. Create a custom configuration file and put it in the container by either creating a custom Dockerfile FROM mongo or mounting it from the host machine to the container. See the MongoDB manual for a full list of configuration file options.
>
> For example, /my/custom/mongod.conf is the path to the custom configuration file. Then start the MongoDB container like the following:
>
> $ docker run --name some-mongo -v /my/custom:/etc/mongo -d mongo --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf

In this way, your docker-compose would be as follows:

```
mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    volumes:
      - ${MONGO_DATA_DB}:/data/db
      - ${MONGO_DATA_CONFIG}:/etc/mongo/
    ports:
      - ${EXPOSED_MONGO_PORT}:27017
    command: --config /etc/mongo/mongod.conf
```

Answer (score 30):

I've tried the accepted answer but mongo log was still quite verbose. Then, following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54701381/4142878), I've omitted the whole log and it's much better in my case:

```
mongo:
    command: mongod --quiet --logpath /dev/null
```

Answer (score 5):

Setting logpath worked for me. It's not showing the logs output instead it's saving to the file.

```
    mongo:
        container_name: mongo
        image: mongo
        restart: unless-stopped
        command: 
            - '--logpath'
            - '/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log'
        ports:
            - '27017:27017'
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative MongoDB image by Bitnami offers this functionality via environment variables in compose file.

https://hub.docker.com/r/bitnami/mongodb. Explained in the section *Configuring system log verbosity level*

Answer (score 0):

Standard Docker container ships with glorious `jq` (at least v7), so I'm using it to only print the message, here's `docker-compose.yaml` snippet:

```yaml
  db:
    image: mongo:7
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: admin
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
    entrypoint: bash -c "docker-entrypoint.sh mongod | jq --unbuffered -r '.msg'"
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data:/data/db
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

And now logs are a lot less offensive, e.g.:

```
Attaching to db-1
db-1  | Initialized wire specification
db-1  | Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
db-1  | Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize.
db-1  | Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService
db-1  | Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService
db-1  | Multi threading initialized
db-1  | Starting TenantMigrationAccessBlockerRegistry
db-1  | MongoDB starting
```

We could get clever-er with `jq`, also note this breaks the Ctrl-C graceful stop (probably a way around that, if anyone has it handy!)