# How Disable logs in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

How can I disable logs in MongoDB?
I'm using a container, and trying to hide the logs using the following code in `docker-compose.yml`

```
mongodb:
  image: mongo
  logging:
    driver: "none"
```

I tried without quotes but it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you really like to run your MongoDB without any logs? This sounds like a very silly idea.

Comment: Redirect logging to /dev/null instead of a file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53806256/docker-compose-suppress-mongodb-output

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, I have been following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54701381/4142878) I've omitted the whole log and it's much better in my case:

```
mongo:
    command: mongod --quiet --logpath /dev/null
```